# how to find a delimiter from a file using pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, delimiter

Is there any way to find delimiter and read that file using spark read.
basically i want to read data from file using spark read

we are expecting three types of delimiter (,  ;  |) i.e. (comma , semicolon , pipe)

```py
csv_data = spark.read.load("path of file", format = "csv",header ='true').cache()
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use **`.textFile`** to get **`first`** row of csv file and capture the **`delimiter`** assign to variable.

- Use the `delimiter` variable to read **csv** file

---

**`Example:`**

```
#sample data
$ cat test.csv
#NAME|AGE|COUNTRY
#a|18|USA
#b|20|Germany
#c|23|USA

#read as textfile and get first row then createdataframe with stringtype
#using regexp_extract function matching only ,|; and extracting assign to delimiter
delimiter=spark.createDataFrame(sc.textFile("file_path/test.csv").take(1),StringType()).\
withColumn("chars",regexp_extract(col("value"),"(,|;|\\|)",1)).\
select("chars").\
collect()[0][0]

delimter
#u'|'

#read csv file with delimiter
spark.read.\
option("delimiter",delimiter).\
option("header",True).\
csv("file_path/test.csv").show()
#+----+---+-------+
#|NAME|AGE|COUNTRY|
#+----+---+-------+
#|   a| 18|    USA|
#|   b| 20|Germany|
#|   c| 23|    USA|
#+----+---+-------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used something like this in my notebook to get delimeter:

```
import re
headerList=sc.textFile("yourPath").take(1)
headerString = ''.join(headerList)

result = re.search("(,|;|\\|)", headerString)
delimiter = result.group()
```